# How to define parent process from child when are having the same process id

Tags: c#, process, ms-office, document

I am using C#.With this code I am trying to open a word document (WINWORD) and get notify when the specific file or file name that I have open from the software has close.
Right now if I open the x.docx file from the software and open another y.docx manualy and close the y.docx file my programs things that was the x.docx because are having the same process name WINWORD.
I have read a lot of articles but i couldn't find anything.Is it possible to do this in any way?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Process mydoc = new Process();
            mydoc.StartInfo.FileName = "op.docx";

            mydoc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\\"; 


            mydoc.Start();
            mydoc.WaitForExit();


            notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
            notifyIcon1.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon(Path.GetFullPath(@"C:\Users\Marios\Desktop\down.ico"));

            notifyIcon1.BalloonTipTitle = "waiting...";
            notifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "Word has has opened...";
            notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(100);

            Displaynotify();
        }

   protected void Displaynotify()
        {
            try
            {
                var processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("WINWORD");
                notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
                notifyIcon1.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon(Path.GetFullPath(@"C:\Users\Marios\Desktop\down.ico"));

                notifyIcon1.BalloonTipTitle = "exited.";
                notifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "Word has exited...";
                notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(100);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
```

**Update 1 with links from the Answer**

I have change my code and now i open it with this way but still i cant do what i want

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        Word.Application oWord = new Word.Application();
   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open("C:\\op.docx");
           oWord.Visible = true;

           ((Word._Document)oDoc).Close();
            // ((Word._Document)oDoc).Close();
           //((Word._Application)oWord).Quit();
          //Displaynotify();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can automate Word from your C# application. In that case you will be able to check what documents are opened at the moment and handle the [Close](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821142(v=office.15).aspx) event of the Document class which is fired when a document is closed.

See [How to automate Microsoft Word to create a new document by using Visual C#](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/316384) for more information and sample code in C#. Also you may find the [C# app automates Word (CSAutomateWord)](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/CSAutomateWord-f422cae5) sample project helpful.

In that case there is no need to run a new process. All the job can be done using Word automation.

Comment: can you please write your answer with my code to see how can be done?

Comment: Take a look at the sample project I mentioned in the post.

Comment: I am and i got error on step 3 with the oWord does not exists in the content.Any way to accept this answer make an example or use my code on your code. The sample project that you have write is not what i need i think.

Comment: Did you a Word reference to the project?

Comment: The sample project illustrates how you can automate Word from your C# application. But to get the job done you need to hadle the Close event where you can check whether the op.docx document is opened or nut. Don't expect to get a ready made solution.

Comment: You need to open an existing file I suppose, not just to create a new one.

Comment: Try to re-read my answer and implement all what I wrote. Where do you handle the Close event?

Comment: ((Word._Document)oDoc).Close(); ((Word._Application)oWord).Quit(); but i have no options to waitforexit or somthing similar for the oDoc that is the op.docx